# How can I make lightcouch output proper errors when deserializing json?

Tags: java, json, couchdb, gson

I have a large CouchDB with large complex json objects. When deserializing them there are sometimes errors because the documents are malformed.

Sadly, the gson encapsulation does not provide more information than:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BLAH but was BLUB
```

And I have to start debugging the whole application to find which document was the one that could not be parsed.

I would like to get hold of the parent document that was being deserialized while the exception happend so that I can log its id.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

So the approach I've found so far is to create a TypeAdapterFactory that logs errors and try to create empty objects or at least return null. This is nice though I get the error at the lowest level of the object hierarchy (i.e. at the point that could not be parsed anymore so I'm missing the information about which document it was.)

Here's the code:

```
public class RobustTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RobustTypeAdapterFactory.class);

  @Override
  public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {

    final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
    return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

        @Override
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value) throws IOException {
            delegate.write(out, value);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public T read(final JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            try {
                return delegate.read(in);
            } catch (IOException | IllegalStateException | JsonSyntaxException e) {
                LOG.info("Could not parse value for {}", type.getRawType());
                in.skipValue();
                try {
                    // try to create empty object
                    return (T) type.getRawType().newInstance();
                } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e1) {
                    // we couldn't create an empty object, so we return null
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    };
  }
}
```

Any better idea?